# Hiding elements of li by its class using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I have many `li` with their class as `ans` in `ul` tag. When clicked in hide button I want to disappear those `li` having `ans` as class and when clicked show button I want all them to be reappeared with little transition if possible.

I have done little JavaScript but it is hiding only first position `li` and and it is not affecting other `li`. and I've no idea how to reappear those.

My `HTML`:

```html
<ul>
    <li class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum?</li>
    <hr>
    <li class="two">Lorem, ipsum.</li>
    <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <hr>
    <li class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
    <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
</ul>

<div class="btn" style="text-align: center;">
                <button class="green" type="button">Show Answer</button>
                <button class="red" type="button">Hide Answer</button>
              </div>
```

Some JavaScript I did:

```js
<script>
        document.getElementsByClassName("red")[0].addEventListener("click", closeBox);
function closeBox(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("ans")[0].style.display = "none";
}
        </script>
```

I would prefer to use JavaScript, I don't want jQuery.

Comment: What is wrong with jQuery? It's just a shorthand for JavaScript. Knowing jQuery can save you time and effort. For example the code could be shortened to `$('.ans').style.display = "none";` if you used jQuery. Just something to think about if you want to seriously dive into web development.

Comment: I agreed but, I want to make it completely offline and we should download different things to make it offline if we use jquery. so..

Comment: @JoelTrauger I think there is nothing wrong with `jQuery`. Sometimes better to understand how vanilla JavaScript works first and for this case I think that is a totally good fit. It's better to start with the basics instead of using one library at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So technically the first issue is that you are trying to access only the first element what `getElementsByClassName` found for you. You need iterate through all the elements by using `Array.prototype.forEach.call` which will help you to toggle visibility for the `li` items.

So based on that I think you can do something like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("red")[0].addEventListener("click", () => setVisiblity(false));
document.getElementsByClassName("green")[0].addEventListener("click", () => setVisiblity(true));

const setVisiblity = (visible) => {
  const ansElements = document.getElementsByClassName('ans');
  const style = visible ? 'list-item' : 'none';

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(ansElements, e => {
    e.style.display = style;
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum?</li>
  <hr>
    <li class="two">Lorem, ipsum.</li>
    <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <hr>
  <li class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
</ul>

<div class="btn" style="text-align: center;">
  <button class="green" type="button">Show Answer</button>
  <button class="red" type="button">Hide Answer</button>
</div>
```

Additionally I agree, `jQuery` for this small code solution would be totally overkill.

I hope this helps!

Comment: jQuery could be overkill, but in a larger project, having jQuery at your fingertips can save many lines of code and improve performance issues caused by reinventing the wheel that has already been perfected in jQuery. By all means, learn pure Javascript first, but many difficult solutions for me have been solved by a few lines of jQuery instead of brute-forcing my way through a pure JS solution.

**jQuery IS JavaScript!**

Comment: @JoelTrauger That's right, in a big project it can help, definitely. I don't have the whole information about the OP's project how big it is, how complex can it be.

Comment: @JoelTrauger, norbitrial  you guys are totally correct. Im new in javascript and jQuery things and i searched and came to know js would be best for my small educational project which i want to provide in offline mode so that. DO you want to give suggestions how can i learn those? and which to learn first?

Comment: @Dibas Definitely learn JavaScript first. I recommend this first so that when you start looking into the different options that jQuery provides you can understand what it is doing and use it to solve larger problems more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem exists here between the `->` arrows `<-`:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("ans") ->[0]<- .style.display = "none";
```

You are selecting only the first element returned by `getElementsByClassName`. To correct this you could do something like this:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("ans");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
  a[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Assign a similar block of code to your **Show Answer** button but set the display to `block` or `inherit` or whatever the current display is.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By accessing the [0] element of the Node-List (Array) `document.getElementsByClassName("ans")[0]` you only get the first element.

You need to iterate through all elements of your NodeList, not only the first one.

I'll append a quick sample solution.

```js
let showButton = document.querySelector('.green');
let hideButton = document.querySelector('.red');

hideButton.addEventListener("click", () => toggleAns(true));
showButton.addEventListener("click", () => toggleAns(false));

function toggleAns(hide) {
  let ansElements = document.querySelectorAll('.ans');
  for (let element of ansElements) {
    element.style.display = hide ? 'none' : 'list-item';
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum?</li>
  <hr>
  <li class="two">Lorem, ipsum.</li>
  <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <hr>
  <li class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
</ul>

<div class="btn" style="text-align: center;">
  <button class="green" type="button">Show Answer</button>
  <button class="red" type="button">Hide Answer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When toggling, the dot disappears on `li` elements because of this line `element.style.display = hide ? 'none' : 'initial';`. I think you need to change from `initial` to `list-item`. That helped my solution.